# "url.createObjectURL is not a function" JS error in page

Tags: javascript

When this same page is put inside ASP.NET Core project throws error.

[image]

```js
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                //this.response is what you're looking for
               // handler(this.response);
               // console.log(this.response, typeof this.response);
                var img = document.getElementById('image');
                var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                img.src = url.createObjectURL(this.response);
            }
        }
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=http://www.cognation.net/profile');
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.send();
```

```html
 <img id="image" />
```

[image]

I think think there is something wrong with my system.
Even the snippet don't work, but in my friend's system it work.

My system

[image]

Friend's system

[image]

Comment: How is tat referred to ASP.NET Core or .NET Core? It's JavaScript code

Comment: @Tseng same page when put in .netcore project, this happen

Comment: I repeat: How is that related to ASP.NET Core? JavaScript runs on the browser, not on the server

Comment: @Tseng I am not sure, something to do with url I think

Comment: But it has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core!! Either your IDE or javascript. No ASP.NET Core involved. The [tag:asp.net-core] tag is completely irrelevant because the issue has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core. So I removed it

Comment: @Tseng I put the same exact page to this project, I get this error.

Comment: Yea, but you added "asp.net core" tag and the problem has **NOTHING** to do with ASP.NET Core. It is a JavaScript problem! You have to use correct tags when you create a question, otherwise the wrong people get to see it. Use Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code or whatever you are using, as its more related to JavaScript/IDE you use

Comment: @Tseng I know that , but this time there is some kind of relation processing the request through the core project. I didn't modify anything,just placed the html page inside this project. But I get the error.

Comment: Please could you include the HTTP response headers in the full fat ASP project where the JS works and the Core project where it fails?

Comment: The code snippet was working when I created it, now it is not working. But when tested now, worked once. Don't know what is happening.

Comment: Try to log `url` along with `URL` and `window` when this happens.

Comment: @Kaiido Didn't get you, what to do ?

Comment: call `console.log(url, URL, window)` before calling `url.createObjectURL`. The only thing we know is one of the 3 is not what it should be, so try to know what it is, then it'll be easier to know why it is what it is. (I suspect some third party script has done some ugly overwriting on the original `URL`.)

Comment: By the way,  what are these `http://browsersecurity.info` scripts ? You are loading two jquery ? Is this something related to [wpad.browsersecurity.info](https://www.google.com/#q=browsersecurity.info&start=10) ?

Comment: Disable all your plugins and extensions, try again.

Comment: In chrome and Firefox also same error. something wrong with my pc setting, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The error is Javascript - for ASP.NET Core to be causing a problem like this the most likely culprit is headers:

- Do you have cross origin headers set that allow access to the API you're calling?
- Do you have Content Security Policy that would block data URI?

In full fat ASP.NET these things are part of the default set up, but in Core they are specific middleware that you have to add.